# Converting Data Table values into array of string values

Tags: c#

method1:

```
public void method1(DataTable ServerGroupIds)
{
   obj.method2(ServerGroupIds);  
}
```

method2 :

```
public static void method2(string[] servergroups)
{
    obj.Message = userName + " has Un-Restricted the Project.";
}
```

Now I want to pass the DataTable values into the method2 String[] servergroups
How can I pass my DataTable values into an array of string values?

Sorry, Forget to mention I have 2 columns in my DataTable. !st column is ProjectId and Second Column is Server Group Id. Now I need only ServerGroup Id's in my array of string

Comment: You don't use `servergroups` in second method

Comment: Can you tell us more about  your datatable? Is it 1 column and N number of rows (1xN)? or is it Many columns and N number of rows (MxN)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public void method1(DataTable ServerGroupIds)
{

   string [] serverGroups = ServerGroupIds.AsEnumerable().Select(t => t.Field<string>("ID")).ToArray<string>();

obj.method2(serverGroups );  

}
```

Don't forget to include `System.Linq`
in `t.Field<string>("ID")`. Replace "ID" with the name of the column in the data table you want to put into the array

Answer (score 0):

For a single row you can do this:

```
var rowAsString = string.Join(", ", ServerGroupIds.Rows[0].ItemArray);
```

Now add all the rows (by looping through your DataTable) `rowAsString` to a list:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < ServerGroupIds.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string rowAsString = string.Join(", ", ServerGroupIds.Rows[i].ItemArray);
    list .Add(rowAsString );
}
string[] array = list.ToArray();
```

And pass to `method2`:

```
obj.method2(array);
```